# file.open() on linux doesn't open my file, how to solve?

Tags: c++, linux, ifstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("./cp.txt");
    if(file.good())
    {
        cout << "done!";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "fail";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

why does my code can't cp.txt file? it is in project folder. i'm using gnu/linux.
as open i mean the program will open it in some text editor i.e:. leafpad

Comment: Have you tried removing the prepended `./`?

Comment: yes i did but it doesn't work. the prompt display "fail".

Comment: You are opening file in your program for read, it is not going to be opened in some kind of editor...

Comment: `file.open` is not intended to open an external editor. It means to open the file within your program, so that your program can read and process its contents. If you want to launch leafpad, use `fork` and `exec` or `system`.

Comment: Make sure that the current directory is the same directory where your file is placed. This is not always the case for IDE's.

Comment: Also, check what are return values of [`file.eof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) and [`file.is_open()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/is_open)

Comment: has read permission this file for you?

Comment: @erip, that's not going to help, `cp.txt` is the same as `./cp.txt`

Comment: @IlyaPopov, that's not going to help either. the `eofbit` cannot get set until you try to read from it, which this program doesn't do. If `good()` is false before performing any I/O then it means it wasn't opened.

Comment: What is "project folder"?

Comment: @JonathanWakely In shell terms, yes. I've run into some instances (namely in that horrible language Java) in which Unix conventions aren't recognized -- namely `~` and `./`.

Comment: @erip, but this isn't Java, and isn't even the shell, this is a path in a C++ program on GNU/Linux, where `./` is defined by the POSIX standard. (`~` is different, that's interpreted by the shell and wouldn't work with `std::ifstream`).

Answer (score 3):

> as open i mean the program will open it in some text editor i.e:. leafpad

That's not going to happen.

When you open an `ifstream` object it means the file is open for reading by that object, it does not mean a text editor is launched and displays the file!

Maybe what you want is:

```
system("leafpad cp.txt");
```

The `system` function runs another command, in this case it runs the command to launch `leafpad` with your file as an argument.

Note that the file will be searched for in the *current working directory* of your program, which is not the same as your "project directory". If you don't know what the current working directory is when your program gets run then you will need to provide an absolute path to the file, not a relative path like `cp.txt`

Answer (score 0):

you have mentioned having a project folder. if you use an IDE,
it might change the current directory of the running executable.
try deleting the file and creating the file within your code eg:

```
ofstream ofile;
ofile.open("./cp.txt");
ofile.close();
```

if you get an output `done!` then search for the file.

Comment: It's probably easier to just add `std::cout << get_current_dir_name() << std::endl;` to the program.